# How to change global value (add function) in the handler of UIAlertAction of UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I would like to show a alert, and I did it. but There is a problem:
I can not change a global value or add a function in the handler of `UIAlertAction` of `UIAlertController`. For example:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "",
                                            message: "Do you want to leave ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                             handler: {
                                action in
self.appDelegate.globalvalue = true 

})
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
alertController.addAction(okAction)
if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverController.sourceView = sender as! UIView
    popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
}
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I add `self.appDelegate.globalvalue = true` in the handler of `UIAlertAction` of `UIAlertController`, but the value `self.appDelegate.globalvalue` is always false... `self.appDelegate.globalvalue` is not changed to be true...

How can I do to change the value in the handler of `UIAlertAction` of `UIAlertController`? or Can I change a global value after clicking OK on the alert ? Thanks for all of yours :)

Comment: Have you tried without self ? and where is this code? Appdelegate or some viewController?

Comment: he needs to use `self` since he references `appDelegate` from within a closure...

Comment: I need use `self`, i define the value in `AppDelegate.swift`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you get a reference to the `AppDelegate`? the following code should work:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var globalValue = false

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "set global value to true", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .Default) { (action) in
            self.appDelegate.globalValue = true
            print("after: \(self.appDelegate.globalValue)")
        }
        alert.addAction(action)

        print("before: \(self.appDelegate.globalValue)")
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get a reference like this `var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate`

Comment: no worries. how do you check if your values has been changed?

Comment: Thank you for your code, it works, but it does not work yesterday, and in fact, I define a global value by a SDK, like this :`var globalSDK : Video?` but  I can not use function of class `Video ` . In this class, there is a function to get how many people use this Video, I can not use this function in the handler of `UIAlertAction `... `globalSDK` is a global value, why I can not use it in the handler of `UIAlertAction ` ? I test this function out of the handler and it works, Could you give me some helps ? Thank you

Comment: `self.appDelegate.globalSDK?.fetchPeoples({ (status, Peoples) in
                        
                        print(Peoples!.count)
                        
                    })`  Peoples is always nil...always nil... I tried, If I do not use alert and I just add it in `@IBAction func close` It works, but if I add it in the handler of `UIAlertAction `, it does not works...

Comment: is it possible for you to share your project so i can take a look?

Comment: Thank your for your help, I fond the problem, infect, there is a wrong enter tow views